# unknown issue in 'header.php' preventing theme from displaying fully

Tags: php, headers

My theme is currently activated and showing only the background image and the "home" link. I believe the issue lies within header.php, but I can't quite figure out what. Any ideas? (Also, is there a php validator I could run my code through, or would a WP theme's code be too WP specific?)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Wordpress <?php bloginfo('version'); ?>" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></title>
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback url'); ?>" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/favicon.ico" />
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="return to the home page" id="logo" /></a>
        </div><!-- end logo -->
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">Home</a></li>
                <?php wp_lists_pages('title_li=&include=9,5,60,62,64'); ?>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- end nav -->
    </div><!-- end header -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_lists_pages` is not a valid function, it's `wp_list_pages` (no **s** at end of **list**).

[enable debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug) in your `wp-config.php` file to see php errors

#### Edit: additional ifo

To answer your other question most advanced editors will check the syntax in your code and will flag errors.  With a function spelling error you would need an advanced IDE like [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) to check core WordPress functions and do code completion while you type.

Comment: Wow three answers all at once... I'm deleting mine and adding to yours.

Answer (score 1):

Your php is simply outputting html, so start there. Try the W3C html/css validator at http://validator.w3.org/ and check "Show Source" under More Options.

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or use the developer tools in [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to see what's loading on your site.

Could be an html error, or javascript. Those tools are very good to use.